# How to store a two's complement number in a long

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion, twos-complement

I am converting a VB6 application to VB.net. The application uses an existing C library I can't change.

**The Problem:** I am expecting a value around `-180` or `180`. The times that I expect `180`, it works. But when I expect `-180`, I get the value `4294967117`. This seems like the C library is returning a 2's complement number, but I don't know how to treat it.

This is the **VB6** code that works:

```
Dim tmp As Long

If GetVal(VAL_A1, tmp) = ERR_VAL_NA Then
    lblAngle(0).Caption = "na"
Else
    lblAngle(0).Caption = tmp
End If
```

This is the **VB.net** code that does not work:

```
    If GetVal(VAL_A1, tmp) = ERR_VAL_NA Then
        txtBoxPhaseAngle1.Text = "na"
    Else
        txtBoxPhaseAngle1.Text = Convert.ToDouble(tmp)
    End If
```

I have also tried:

```
 txtBoxPhaseAngle1.Text = Convert.ToInt32(tmp)

txtBoxPhaseAngle1.Text = tmp
```

**EDIT :**

How I declare the C function:

```
 Declare Function GetVal Lib "Z:\Devel\RelayAPI\Debug\RelayAPI.dll" (ByVal what As 
Integer, ByRef val As Long) As Byte
```

Snippets from the `GetVal` function in the C code:

```
BYTE __stdcall GetVal(WORD what, long *val){
    DWORD relaydate;
    BYTE tmpb;
    DWORD tmpd;
    long tmp;

    ...

        switch(what){

            case VAL_A1:
                tmpb=RelayAPI_Scaled;
                if(tmpd<6){
                    *val=(short)((WORD)mon[38]+((WORD)mon[39]<<8));
                }else{
                    *val=(short)((WORD)mon[32]+((WORD)mon[33]<<8));
                }
            break;

   break;
}
```

Comment: it might be how you get the value from the C lib; esp if this is a port from VB6

Comment: I will update my question with some more information on the function from the C library. I can change the C code if I absolutely have to, but it is really not ideal.

Comment: What does your dllimport function look like? You're right that the bits for -180 and 4294967117 look identical -- did you forget to change the dllimport declaration from `long` to `integer` when you converted from VB6?

Comment: Have you considered doing all of the bitwise math to just convert the number from twos compliment back to an integer value?  Probably wouldn't be the cleanest code, but it might work.

Comment: Maybe it's returning a 32bit number, not a 64bit.

Comment: @pmcoltrane I have updated my question with the dllimport declaration.

Comment: @JuiCe as `the_lotus` said, the function is probably returning a 32-bit value. In VB6, `Long` is 32-bits, but a VB.NET `Long` is 64-bits. The C function uses `long`, which according to spec is guaranteed to be "at least 32-bits". Try changing your dllimport declaration to `ByRef val As Integer` and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you guys, changing my dllimport declaration to use an `Integer` solved my problem. If either @the_lotus or @pmcoltrane would put that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When upgrading from VB6, you need to be aware that some data types have changed. In VB6, an `Integer` is 16-bits, and a `Long` is 32-bits. In VB.NET, though, an `Integer` is 32-bits and a `Long` is 64-bits.

In the C function, you have `long *val`, and a C `long` is "at least 32-bits" according to spec, so presumably your C-function is returning a 32-bit integer. However, VB.NET now believes that it's a `Long` (64-bit) value, and interprets it as such -- `4294967117` instead of `-180`.

If you change your VB.NET declaration of the `val` parameter to `ByRef val As Integer`, you will probably see the correct return value.